# $.getJSON call works on CHROME ...does NOT on IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-chrome, getjson

I am using an  Asp.Net MVC PartialView page that supposed to make a call to a Server Action every 5 seconds.

This is the action procedure (note it returns null):

```
    public ActionResult StillOnline()
    {
        // bla bla bla
        return null;
    }
```

This is the HTML javascript that supposed to call that procedure every 5 seconds:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function {
                         var url = '<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>';
                         $.getJSON(url, null, null);}
                    , 10000);
                });
</script>
```

With Chrome ...it executes the call every 5 seconds (yuhuuu)
With IE ...the calls gets executed only once.

ERROR MESSAGE:
None, IE does NOT throw an error.

MY GOAL:
Like I said, I need to have my ASP.Net PartialView call the server action every 5 seconds. No return is expected from the server.

Maybe you know a better way to achieve that?

:--)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is the request not being sent? Nothing happening on response, such as error messages? (Though, to be fair, the function defined doesn't have any parameters to pass through, so IE might be complaining about that.)

Comment: Are you getting any error for that?

Comment: he is getting error, its just being swallowed by the browser just like all errors inside DOM even handlers.

Comment: How do I see IE Errors ..if they are swallowed by IE?

Any help where I could get on the internet a site that tells me the proper syntax for such simple call working in IE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
 setInterval(function UpdateMyStatus() {
```

is not valid syntax. You want

```
  setInterval(function() {
```

I'm pretty sure IE throws an error message for this. Always check the error output first, it'll tell you what's wrong in most cases.

Comment: I tried that and IE now calls the server action only once. Chrome still calls it every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Filu dude, you still have an obvious syntax error in there. Please just do what Pekka told you.

Comment: I removed the name "UpdateMyStatus" (see updated initial thread text) ..and still get ONE call only in IE.

What else am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess problem is with IE cache, try this out it might help.


$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function {
                     $.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false});
                     var url = '<%: Url.Action("StillOnline", "Account") %>';
                     $.getJSON(url, null, null);}
                , 10000);
            });
```